# Is it possible to rollback a migration from Hyper-V to Azure

Tags: azure, hyper-v, failover, scvmm, recovery-services

I am migrating VMs from Hyper-V to Azure using the integration among SCVMM and the Azure Replication Service.

For a given VM, I performed successfully the test failover, I validated the outcome, I cleaned it up, the failover has completed successfully, and the portal is giving me the options to either:

- Commit
- Change recovery point
- Complete Migration
- Disable Replication.

Problem is, for this given VM I'd like to rollback the migration instead, so that the Hyper-V VM becomes the primary and the protection restarts.

I understand I could disable replication and reconfigure a new replication, but that would mean starting protection from scratch.

Is there a way to achieve a rollback at this point in time without disabling replication?